# Determine Value of a Cell by two variables

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, foreach

**My Issue:**

I want to loop through a range, and whenever it finds a duplicate value, it should take the amount from the cell with offset to the right of it, and add that to the value of the first Cells amount. I have a macro, which can determine if it finds a duplicate, but if it has several duplicates, then I want it to redo the task, but just continue to find the duplicates and add up the amount :)

**What I have so far:**

```
    Sub LoopThroughRangeAndFindDuplicates ()

    NumberOne = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Bilagsnr.").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindNo, 1, "")
    rng1 = NumberOne & ":" & Number & LastRow

    No1Off = sht.Range(NumberOne).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)

For Each c In sht.Range(rng1).Cells
    rngOff1 = No1Off & ":" & Number & LastRow + 1
        With Wf
        n = .CountIfs(Range(rngOff1), c)
            If n > 0 Then
                CDuplicate = sht.Range(rngOff1).Find(c).Address(False, False, xlA1)
                CDuplicateSub = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CDuplicate, Number, Amount)
                CDuplicateSubValue = sht.Range(CDuplicateSub).Value
                CValue = c.Address(False, False, xlA1)
                CValueSub = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CValue, Number, Amount)
                CValueSubValue = sht.Range(CValueSub).Value
                sht.Range(CValueSub).Value = CValueSubValue + CDuplicateSubValue
            End If
    End With
    No1Off = sht.Range(No1Off).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)
Next c
```

**Goal:**

As requested in the above, I want the macro to redo the `If n > 0 Then` if it has more duplicates than x. How should I write my code, to get it to look for several duplicates, and add them up, before continuing, without making a `For Each` string that will be really long? :)

Comment: How about change taking advantage of `SUMIF` worksheet function. Much simpler. Probably easier to change entire approach and get a list of duplicate values first then write formula against each of those values.

Comment: Or use a Pivot table?

Comment: @FunThomas so far a pivot table has just ruined the purpose I need the data for.. Therefore I haven’t used that method

Comment: @ScottHoltzman so I can use SUMIF on the cell to the right?? And thereby get it to sum up everything within the range to just the cell to the left? I need to delete the duplicate rows afterwards :)

Comment: Yes. You can do exactly that. But if you are going to delete rows and you want to loop through the list, make sure you loop backwards.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Hmmm, okay :) I’ll see what I can put together...